# Aid me in understanding the components of this regular expression

Tags: regex

What does this mean?

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Here is what I know so far: ^ means the string must begin with a letter or a digit, * means zero or more occurences, but how do you mix * and $? That last part confuses me.

Comment: Since you know `^` means the beginning of the string, surely you know what `$` would mean?

Comment: that means matching zero or more occurrences of letters or digits until the end of the string ($).  /^$/ matches an empty string ('').

Answer (score 5):

There are three components to this regex:

1. `^` matches the start of the string;
2. `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` matches zero or more characters, where each character can be a letter or a digit;
3. `$` matches the end of the string.

In summary, the regex matches any string (including the empty one) that consists entirely of letters and digits.

Comment: What about (deliver.*)?  Does it mean match "deliver" followed by any character other than '\n' and thank you can have zero or more of those? I mean, what does the * apply to?

Comment: @user1007632: In that example, it applies to the dot.

Answer (score 2):

`^` marks the start of an expression and `$` marks the end.  So it means a string that is comprised entirely of 0 or more letters (uppercase or lowercase) or digits.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mix * and $. * is a quantifier as you have noted and it applied to the previous group/character in your case a character class.

Also ^ means the beginning of the string. Essentially a place not a character. They are called anchors. Respectively $ means the end of the string.

Finally your regex as it is written can match nothing or a string which consists of random number of digits and a-z characters irrespective of case.

Comment: and $ delimits the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

It means:
line that contains only (latin letter or digit) 0 or more times.

Answer (score 0):

The `*` should apply to the `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. `$` should mean end of line or end of input, so essentially the whole string should consist of lowercase and uppercase letters, and digits.